# How to do a One OnTouchListener for many imageviews

Tags: android

I'm doing a project and i need to handle about 25 ImageViews with one OnTouchListene, I have done OnClickListener but i have problem in OnTouchListener.

Following is the OnTouchListener code :

**Please read the comments in the code for more details about what i need help in.**

```
public View.OnTouchListener imgSwipe = new OnSwipeTouchListener(){

//I have added (View v) to handle the touched ImageView, But not working.

    public boolean onSwipeTop(View v) {
        if(v == m1)){
           //Do something
        }
        else if(v == m2){
     //Do something
        }

     // Here to add the remains ImageView such as m3, m4 ... m25.

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

};
```

And the OnSwipeTouchListener() class code is :

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        result = onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        result = onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        result = onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        result = onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public boolean onSwipeRight() {
    return false;
}

public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
    return false;
}

public boolean onSwipeTop() {
    return false;
}

public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Any ideas about how to handle all ImageViews touches in one OnTouchListener ?

Thanks.

Comment: class MyImageView extends ImageView implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener ...

Comment: What should this class do ? i need to know the touched object (ImageView) because i want to use the ID in another function.

Comment: implement GestureDetector.OnGestureListener and just use `this` inside onFling